Add a custom field for sorting the products in a specific category WOOCOMMERCE - Second try

Hi, mainly I need to add an "orderby filter selection" in the above dropdown menu, in WOO product category widget, based on an ACF field.
The final "OrderBy dropdown menu" content i'd like to achieve: menu_order, id date, author, etc..., MY_ACF_Product_Field.
And obviously add the logic to handle that new sorting order.
Which file I have to edit? Which hook I've to call?
Thanks in advance Frank
